# Why mysql return only one record in group concat for blob file in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I  tried to select image file in comma seperated form using group contact but it returns only one  record in one row.But it works properly with other datatypes like varchar,int.How can i fix/this?Thanks in advance...

Here is my code...

```
CREATE TABLE `images` (
    `id` INT(222) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
    `image` BLOB NOT NULL ,
    `user_id` INT(222) NOT NULL ,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Insert data:

```
INSERT INTO `images`(`id`,`images`,`user_id`) VALUES ('','forest.png','1')
INSERT INTO `images`(`id`,`images`,`user_id`) VALUES ('','forest2.png','1')
INSERT INTO `images`(`id`,`images`,`user_id`) VALUES ('','forest3.png','2')
INSERT INTO `images`(`id`,`images`,`user_id`) VALUES ('','forest1.png','1')
```

I have tried...

```
select 
     group_concat(image separator ', ') image
from   images
group by user_id
```

I have expected the result...

```
image
blob1,blob2,blob3.....
```

Comment: Also specify the expected result!

Comment: not two only one....

Comment: @Jeevan please check again the values from `user_id`. As @basha04 suggested you might have an issue there.

Comment: Check in MySQL Workbench the output limit. In the top menu there is a select called *Limit to x rows*. Also check in the bottom frame, in the *Action Output* the final query and look the *LIMIT 0, x* statement.